# Trying to rename module after import error 7874 can't find module1 object

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to import exported objects from another database. The file extension is vba. I have created a loop to go through all the objects. My loop does go through all the files properly. The loop does import a module as Module 1 for the first file. I want to rename the module from module 1 to the previous module name.

I am working with MS Access office 365.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles2()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strNewFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strNewPath As String
    Dim strDBName As String
    Dim strModName As String

    strDBName = Application.CurrentProject.Name
    strPath = ("C:\Users\Parents\Google Drive\Access Files\File7\")
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Debug.Print strFile
        Debug.Print strPath

        strNewFile = Replace(strFile, ".vba", ".txt", 1, , vbTextCompare)
        Debug.Print strNewFile

        Name strPath & strFile As strPath & strNewFile
        strNewPath = strPath & strFile
        strModName = Replace(strNewFile, ".txt", "")
        Debug.Print strModName
        VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import strNewPath
        VBProj.VBComponents("Module 1").Name = strModName 'error 424 
        DoCmd.Rename strModName, acModule, "Module1" 'error 7874

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you need to save the module first, then rename it.

Comment: How do you export? Seems like`Attribute VB_Name`is missing. With that set, the module gets imported with its name before export.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name directly, but you can change a property instead, like this:

```
VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Module 1").Properties("Name").Value = strModName
```

Comment: I changed the line to: VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Properties("Name1").Value = strModName  I am getting error 438 object doesn't support this property

Comment: Because there is no Property`Name1`, only`Name`! Try`VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Properties("Name").Value = strModName` or better`VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import(strNewPath).Properties("Name").Value = strModName`as`Import`returns the imported`VBComponent`, that you want to rename (a Module with a predefined name won't be named`Module1`,what causes your code to fail. Export a Module and open it in a text-viewer to see`Attribute VB_Name`).

Comment: After about the 40th module I get a runtime error 50021 Input past end of file. I tried to add an if statement if not EOF then but that causes compile error argument not optional